# Playing an audio file in java

Tags: java, file, audio, playback, restart

My goal is to make a program that displays a pop up window with a single button called `play`. I am using an inner class and action listener. The button does in fact play the audio clip. Now what I would like to do is make it so every time I hit the play button it plays it from the beginning and I do not hear more than one instance of the clip being played in it's completion. Here is the code I have for the inner class only:

```
private class PlaySound implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String filename = "/Users/philipgouldman/Desktop/iPhoneRingtones/Dummy_Yeah.wav";

        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename)));
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

}
```

I would appreciate any tips or suggestions to achieve this goal. I read on the Clip Interface javadoc that if the user wants the action to restart to simply invoke `stop` following `setFramePosition(0)`. I can't say I quite understand what that means. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Clip` Object outside of this handle so that its state can be investigated later.

e.g.

```
private class PlaySound implements ActionListener {

    private Clip clip = null;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String filename = "/Users/philipgouldman/Desktop/iPhoneRingtones/Dummy_Yeah.wav";

        try {
            if (clip == null) {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename)));
            }
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Eclipse, my editor can't compile that in particular for the declaration and initialization of the static Clip object. It says it cannot be declared in a non static inner type

Comment: UPDATE: took out the static modifier, also re pasted my file path, works just like I wanted it to thank you :)

Comment: My reputation is < 15 atm. So it will record it but not show it